# How to reduce large performance variance in HDFS namenode

Tags: hdfs, presto

I'm experiencing serious performance issue in HDFS namenode (v2.7) response time. Particularly during the peak traffic time, my HDFS namenode is overloaded and some DFS operations like listing a directory can take a long time, which affects the query response time for my Presto and other Hadoop applications. Any suggestions on the solution?

Answer (score 0):

My team faced similar challenges in high latency Namenode RPC latency during peak time before. We used multi-layers architecture to solve the problems. To be more concrete, we have a big, highly utilized Hadoop cluster (tens of thousand nodes), and around it, we have smaller computing clusters (about 1 thousand nodes), running Presto and other different frameworks on Alluxio serving as a caching layer to the big HDFS cluster. In this way, the data and metadata service pressure will be shielded by Alluxio deployment by a lot.

For more, you can look at this [Strata Presentation](https://www.slideshare.net/Alluxio/using-alluxio-as-a-fault-tolerant-pluggable-optimization-component-to-compute-frameworks-of-jd-system).